# Obtaining element of chunked data with Perl

Tags: linux, perl, unix

I have a data that looks like this:

```
some info
some info

[Term]
id: GO:0000001
name: mitochondrion inheritance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The distribution of mitochondria, including the mitochondrial genome, into daughter cells after mitosis or meiosis, mediated by interactions between mitochondria and the cy
synonym: "mitochondrial inheritance" EXACT []
is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance
is_a: GO:0048311 ! mitochondrion distribution

[Term]
id: GO:0000002
name: mitochondrial genome maintenance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The maintenance of the structure and integrity of the mitochondrial genome; includes replication and segregation of the mitochondrial chromosome." [GOC:ai, GOC:vw]
is_a: GO:0007005 ! mitochondrion organization

[Typedef]
id: regulates
name: regulates
xref: RO:0002211
transitive_over: part_of ! part_of
```

Note that the end of that file contain white space.

What I want to do is to parse each chunk that starts with `[Term]` and obtain `id`,`name` and `namespace`. At the end of the day a hash of array like this:

```
$VAR = ['GO:0000001' => ["mitochondrion inheritance","biological_process"],
        'GO:0000002' => ["mitochondrial genome maintenance","biological_process"];
```

How can I go about it Perl?

I'm stuck with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
my %bighash;
while(<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my $line = $_;

  my $term = "";
  my $id = "";
  my $name ="";
  my $namespace ="";
  if ($line =~ /^\[Term/) { 
   $term = $line;
  }
  elsif ($line =~ /^id: (.*)/) {
   $id = $1;
  }
  elsif ($line =~ /^name: (.*)/) {
   $name = $1;
  }
  elsif ($line =~ /^namespace: (.*)/) {
   $namespace = $1;
  }
  elsif ($line =~ /$/) {
     $bighash{$id}{$name} = $namespace;
  }

}

print Dumper \%bighash;



__DATA__
some info
some info

[Term]
id: GO:0000001
name: mitochondrion inheritance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The distribution of mitochondria, including the mitochondrial genome, into daughter cells after mitosis or meiosis, mediated by interactions between mitochondria and the cy
synonym: "mitochondrial inheritance" EXACT []
is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance
is_a: GO:0048311 ! mitochondrion distribution

[Term]
id: GO:0000002
name: mitochondrial genome maintenance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The maintenance of the structure and integrity of the mitochondrial genome; includes replication and segregation of the mitochondrial chromosome." [GOC:ai, GOC:vw]
is_a: GO:0007005 ! mitochondrion organization

[Typedef]
id: regulates
name: regulates
xref: RO:0002211
transitive_over: part_of ! part_of
```

Test here: https://eval.in/80497

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set Perl's input record separator to `''` (`local $/ = '';`), you'll read the data in *paragraph* mode, i.e., in chunks separated by a blank line.  Next, you can use regexes to capture the parts you need from within that chunk.  For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

local $/ = '';
my %hash;

while (<DATA>) {
    next unless /^\[Term\]/;

    my ($id)        = /id:\s+(.+)/;
    my ($name)      = /name:\s+(.+)/;
    my ($namespace) = /namespace:\s+(.+)/;

    push @{ $hash{$id} }, ( $name, $namespace );
}

print Dumper \%hash;

__DATA__
[Term]
id: GO:0000001
name: mitochondrion inheritance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The distribution of mitochondria, including the mitochondrial genome, into daughter cells after mitosis or meiosis, mediated by interactions between mitochondria and the cy
synonym: "mitochondrial inheritance" EXACT []
is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance
is_a: GO:0048311 ! mitochondrion distribution

[Term]
id: GO:0000002
name: mitochondrial genome maintenance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The maintenance of the structure and integrity of the mitochondrial genome; includes replication and segregation of the mitochondrial chromosome." [GOC:ai, GOC:vw]
is_a: GO:0007005 ! mitochondrion organization

[Typedef]
id: regulates
name: regulates
xref: RO:0002211
transitive_over: part_of ! part_of
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'GO:0000001' => [
                            'mitochondrion inheritance',
                            'biological_process'
                          ],
          'GO:0000002' => [
                            'mitochondrial genome maintenance',
                            'biological_process'
                          ]
        };
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a nice trick that may help.  Perl has a `$/` variable that defines the "input record separator" -- when you read an input record with `<DATA>`, it will read up until it encounters whatever `$/` is set to, and then return all that data.

Normally `$/` is set to the newline character, so `<DATA>` returns one line at a time from the file.  But if you set it to the empty string `""`, then each read will return all of the data until the next empty line or series of empty lines

```
$/ = "";
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;        # remove the trailing newlines
    # $_ now contains a whole blank-line-separated chunk
    if (/^\[Term\]/) {
        ...
        # parse the [Term] chunk here
        ...
    }
}
```

Inside the loop, you can parse the chunk by splitting it into lines, then splitting each line on the `:` string to obtain a key and value. At that point you can put the key and value for that chunk into whatever kind of structure you like.